# What is the best way to recognize computer from rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to recognize computer from rails  application?

will  `req.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` work for this?

Comment: what do you mean by recognizing? to tell if visitor is using a pc/laptop and not a mobile device?

Comment: Do you mean fingerprinting?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to distinguish whether a human or a bot has filled in a form? One simple way would be to test how much time the user took to fill in the form, for example, the difference between `Time.current` in your `new` action and your `create` action.